# Как сделать разную паузу для отдельных слайдов в Flexlider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

Использую плагин [Flexslider](https://github.com/woocommerce/FlexSlider/wiki) для создания слайдшоу. При стандартном поведении пауза для всех слайдов одинаковая и задаётся параметром `slideshowSpeed`. Интересует вопрос, как можно сделать, чтобы для каждого слайда было своя длительность паузы? В [документации](https://github.com/woocommerce/FlexSlider/wiki/FlexSlider-Properties) не нашёл ответ на этот вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function() {

  $hook = $('.flexslider');
  $hook.flexslider({
    animation: $hook.data('animation'),
    controlNav: $hook.data('control-nav'),
    slideshow: $hook.data('slideshow'),
    startAt: $hook.data('start-at'),
    pauseOnHover: false,
    after: function(slider) {
      slider.stop();
      slider.vars.slideshowSpeed = $(slider.slides[slider.currentSlide]).data('duration');
      slider.play();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.2.2/flexslider-min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.2.2/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>

<div class="flexslider" data-animation="fade" data-control-nav="false" data-slideshow="true" data-start-at="0">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li data-duration="100">
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" alt="Alt" />
    </li>
    <li data-duration="2000">
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg" alt="Alt Text" />
    </li>
    <li data-duration="100">
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg" alt="Alt Text" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @ruslan-k большое спасибо, но у вашего способа есть один баг - при первом показе первого слайда задержка происходит дефолтная.